# Received an error when uploading a file to DoubleClick

Tags: banner, double-click, ads, banner-ads, double-click-advertising

Does anyone know what the error "**You uploaded the wrong number of assets with Enabler components for this creative. The creative must have exactly 2 asset(s) with Enabler."** means?

I'm assuming DoubleClick changed something on their end. I tried uploading old creative and received the same error.

I am using Hype3 to create my ad. Here is the script in the head of the file. I wonder if something has changed with the enabler.

```html
  <head>
   
 <script src="https://s0.2mdn.net/ads/studio/Enabler.js"></script>
 <meta name="ad.size" content="width=1000,height=90">


<script>
  // If true, start function. If false, listen for INIT.
  window.onload = function() {
    if (Enabler.isInitialized()) {
      enablerInitHandler();
    } else {
      Enabler.addEventListener(studio.events.StudioEvent.INIT, enablerInitHandler);
    }
  }

  function enablerInitHandler() {
    // Start ad, initialize animation,
    // load in your image assets, call Enabler methods,
    // and/or include other Studio modules.
    // Also, you can start the Polite Load
  }

  //If true, start function. If false, listen for VISIBLE.
  //So your pageLoadedHandler function will look like the following:

  function pageLoadedHandler() {
    if (Enabler.isVisible()) {
      adVisibilityHandler();
    } else {
      Enabler.addEventListener(studio.events.StudioEvent.VISIBLE,
      adVisibilityHandler);
    }
  } 
  
  function bgExitHandler1(e) {
    Enabler.exitOverride('Background Exit1', 'URL');
  }
  
  function exitClose(e) {
    Enabler.reportManualClose();
    Enabler.close();
  }
  
  document.getElementById('exit').addEventListener('click', bgExitHandler1, false);
  document.getElementById('close_btn').addEventListener('click', exitClose, false);
 
</script>
<head>
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the issue was caused by the fact that I chose the wrong format. I needed to choose 'interstitial' in order for it to work with my files.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a similar error if you don't add the enabler  tag as described here:
https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/2672553?hl=en&ref_topic=2672541